# Opening a Silverlight dialog from the ribbon in Crm 2011

Tags: silverlight, ribbon, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Has anybody been able to open a Silverlight dialog by clicking on a button from the ribbon in Dynamics CRM 2011 (On-Premise) ? I understand that you can only call a javascript, html or outlook from the ribbon but haven't been able to launch even the html page generated in my Silverlight project.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Silverlight dialog directly from the ribbon in this way:

```
<Actions>
 <Url Address="$webresource:new_/SilverlightFromRibbonTestPage.html" PassParams="true"></Url>
</Actions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing a window.open in your JScript that points to your Silverlight app?

```
window.open("http://www.MySilverlightUrl.com","MySilverlightApp");
```

I'm a little confused because you mention its a Silverlight dialog.  Does this have any connection with the CRM 2011 dialogs (user-driven workflow) or just what you call the custom application?